# Hibernate and Jboss 6.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I'm having problems when I'm trying to deploy on JBoss 6.0 a roo spring application.
The exception I'm getting is:
"Deployment "*here goes my war file*/" is in error due to the following reason(s): `java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/hibernate/bytecode/cglib/CglibClassTransformer, method: doTransform signature: (Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;[B)[B) Incompatible object argument for function call"`

Please if anybody can help me. I'm new into JBoss and can't find the answer for it.
Probably it is wrong version of classes but which?

Many thanks for any help!
Agata

Comment: Can you post the output of `mvn dependency:tree` (mentioning the versions of libraries you're using in your question is a good practice by the way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's a clash between the versions of CGLIB used by Hibernate and Spring.  This problem is what OSGi was born to solve.  Each one could have their own if you could use higher-order packaging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that it is problem with CGLIB but don't know how to solve it. For the time being I don't want to use OSGI.  I will try with my pom.xml and maybe change vesrions of hibernate?

Comment: You don't have a choice - Spring and Hibernate need them for dynamic proxy generation.  Give it a go with pom.xml and version changes.